# WHAT'S SVM or SVR MODEL

Tags: model, machine-learning, svm

What's SVM OR SVR Model?
What determine the SVM model?

Before, I think that if you know the SVM Kernel type (e.g. RBF kernel) and you know the exact parameter, like -C, -gama, -epsilon in SVR, The model is determined.

After that, I think that the model should be relative to the SVs, and the SVs are some training examples, so the model should be determined by the training examples. Is that right?

How to understand the SVM model? What are the model dependent on? What's the inner of the model. Thanks!

If you want to give an example, I'd prefer the LIBSVM toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVM model is a following classification function

```
cl(x) = sgn( SUM_i y_i alpha_i K( SV_i, x ) + b )
```

where

- y_i is a label of i'th support vector (-1 or +1)
- alpha_i is i'th support vector lagrange multiplier found during optimization
- SV_i is i'th support vector
- K( x,y ) is used kernel function
- b is intercept term, found during optimization

The interpretation comes directly from its derivation, if phi(x) is a *Kernel space transition function* (meaning that K(x,y)= < phi(x),phi(y) >) than:

```
w = SUM_i y_i alpha_i phi( SV_i )
```

is the **normal** (perpendicular vector) of the separating hyperplane. So the above classification formula simply checks whether given point is on one or another side of this hyperplane. The core hardness with interpretation comes from the fact that phi(x) transforms point to possibly very complex space, in kase of RBF kernel, phi(x) transforms points into **functions** space, meaning that each point becomes a function, and your hyperplane is a hyperplane in function space. It is a bit abstract concept, yet still valid.